# Null endpoint is passed when using soap ui project custom properties

Tags: web-services, automation, soapui

I am trying to pass the endpoint for a project using the project custom properties. Say I created a custom property "EndPoint" and am trying to pass http://${#Project#EndPoint} in the endpoint field for the get request, it is throwing me null response. The request sent is not having the endpoint value.

```
GET http://null///int/locations/v1/destinations?
```

Should we able to override the properties?

Comment: What is the value defined for project custom property `EndPoint`?

Comment: an IP address for the endpoint

Comment: Would it be possible to show raw request?

Comment: This is a part of raw request GET http://null///int/locations/v1/destinations?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in the property name ?